# Java JDBC Get string primary key value after inserting data in table

Tags: java, jdbc

**BookTable**

```
isbn VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
bookTitle VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
publisher VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL, 
copyRight  BLOB(45) NOT NULL,
isBookAvailable TINYINT(0) NOT NULL
UNIQUE(isbn)
```

**AuthorTable**

```
authorId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
firtName VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, 
lastName VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
```

**AuthorBooTable**

```
authorIsbnId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
isbn INT NOT NULL, 
authorId INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ( authorIsbnId ), 
FOREIGN KEY (isbn) REFERENCES  BookTable (isbn) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (authorId) REFERENCES AuthorTable (authorId) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

So far, I know how to get the authorId by using `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` since the keys for the author table are generated automatically through "AUTO_INCREMENT". I need the both primary keys of the authorId from authorTable and isbn from the BookTable so that I can be able to create the relationship in the AuthorBookTable before saving  the data to the database. My question, how can I get the isbn number from BookTable since it's a string and not "AUTO_INCREMENTED"? I have tried calling `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` but doesn't return the primary key for the Book isbn primary key. Your help will be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: Which DBMS product and JDBC driver (version) are you using?

Comment: After inserting data into which table? With what SQL?

Comment: Why do you need to get the isbn, you just inserted it, so you should already have it. And if not, why can't you just select it?

Comment: I am using mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin. The creation of the tables in the database is working great. the only problem I have is getting the isbn primary key from the BookTable. How do I determine the JBDC driver? I don't any clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one..

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(insertsql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)
```

Instead of `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` ,you can use column names:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(insertsql, new String[]{"isbn"}) 
            //put the name of the primary key column
    ps.executeUpdate();

    rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
    if (rs.next()) {
        generatedKey = rs.getString(1);
    }
```

Hope this fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you! You are a life saver :)

Comment: @Intelligent,Glad to know.Its working. Please select the tick mark.If it found helpful.